# What kind of cable do I need to transfer files between laptops: MacBook Pro and Samsung?

Tags: macbook, file-transfer

As a target I need to copy files from Samsung to Macbook to reset all hard disk on Samsung.

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you considered things like external hard drives, USB sticks, etc.? Or is that not an option?

Comment: Get some storage and you don’t need to use your MacBook at all. All other options are really just too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External hard drives, memory sticks, flash drives, external SSDs (because reasons), cloud storage (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1455), etc. you name it. Anything that is (preferrably) formatted to exFAT (or MSDOS?) should do the job.

Refer more to Option 2 of this link: http://www.mactip.net/guide-how-to-format-an-external-drive-to-work-seamlessly-with-macs-and-pcs-without-third-party-software/

Comment: Any kind of cable?

Comment: Just connect your external drive (if you have one) to your PC/Mac. If the machine recognizes it then you're good to go. That also mean what ever cable you are using works.